# Firefox-57: hides audio element when height is supplied through css but works on other browsers and versions

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, html5-audio

My HTML is as follows:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <table>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <audio src="audio1.mp3" controls="controls"></audio>
                </td>
                <td title="3b15f6c1fee191">3b15f6c1fee191</td>
                <td ></td>
                <td ></td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <div>
        <table>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <audio src="audio2.mp3" controls="controls"></audio>
                </td>
                <td title="3c15f6c1fee1f1">3c15f6c1fee1f1</td>
                <td ></td>
                <td ></td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <div>
        <table>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <audio src="audio3.mp3" controls="controls"></audio>
                </td>
                <td title="`">3a15f6bff18421</td>
                <td ></td>
                <td ></td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
......
```

> Where audio tag has deferent height on deferent browsers e.g. it shows as follows in firefox-57:

[image: without css]

> To overcome that I added following css to my dom

```
audio{
  height:30px
}
```

> But in firefox-57 it hides audio tags as follows:

[image: hide Audio tag]

> Which run good in other browsers as follows:
>   [image: working fine in chrome]

I'm confused How to bring this seamless behaviour of height across browsers.

Answer (score 1):

FF supports (correctly) the `width` `height` attribute only on `<video>` tags, so, I guess, it isn't possible to set them through CSS as well for the `<audio>` one.

`width` and `height` are meant to control the appearance, size and ratio of video itself rather than it's pagination; on `<audio>` there isn't any `width` or `height` to be set up.

Other browsers use them to set dimensions of the audio player itself, but anyway the FF behaviour looks like meaningful to me anyway.

If your problem is correctly spacing and paginate elements you'd better apply CSS height to the table cells... something like:

```
tr {
  height:30px
}
```

more info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Video_and_audio_content)

Being  an inline element, you might anyway try:

```
audio {
  width:20px;
  height:30px;
  display: block
}
```

probably it will work on with, but hardly on height...